# What are the password requirements for the new Planewalker points system?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What are the requirements for [the new planeswalker points login system](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/PlaneswalkerPoints/)? I attempted to log in with my DCI number today (which I don't do often) and it informed me I needed to upgrade my account. It was clear on the requirements for the user id but there are none listed for the password on screen and it refuses to accept anything I can think of.

My first instinct was to goto Wizard's support system, but it requires you to be logged in to contact them so I am locked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the "?" next to the field where you have to enter your new password, and it tells you the password requirements.

> Password Must Contain:
>
> - Minimum of 7 characters
> - Maximum of 29 characters
> - Uppercase letter (1 or more)
> - Lowercase letter (1 or more)
> - Number (0–9)
> - Special character (e.g., !, $, *, etc.)
>
> Passwords Cannot Be:
>
> - Your Login ID
> - Your email address
> - Your screen name
> - Your DCI number
> - A drawing of your favorite Planeswalker

Comment: What's your source for this information?

Comment: I just clicked on the "?" next to the field where you have to enter your new password when you update your account.

Comment: Interesting, I had no such "?". New software, new bugs I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to upgrade my account with a password consisting of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers, and special symbols. I was able to use a 13 character password, so if there is a minimum length, it is no more than 13.

In general, some common requirements for passwords are:

- Must contain at least one uppercase letter, lowercase letter, number, and special symbol (printable non-alphanumeric characters)
- Must be at least 8 characters long
- Must not contain any dictionary word of length at least 3
- Must not contain your username

Comment: I think it was the symbol I was forgetting to try. I'm giving the answer to you for now since you got here first, but if someone references anything from Wizards I'll change it.